# How to get the selected value of a dynamically created selectlist component

Tags: dynamic, controller, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am not sure whether this is even possible, but I am trying to get the values of dynamically created selectlists in a VisualForce Apex controller class.

I am dynamically creating a selectlist for each field in a particular object (e.g. Contact) using the code below, but now I do not know how to get the selected value back. I have tried setting the value of each in the constructor and on a separate line (not in code sample below), but this does not seem to work.

VisualForce page:

```
<apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!contactPageBlockSection}" />
```

Apex controller:

```
public Component.Apex.PageBlockSection GetContactPageBlockSection(string objectName)   
{
    Map<string, Schema.SObjectField> FieldMap;
    FieldMap = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
    Set<string> FieldSet = FieldMap.keySet();
    List<string> FieldList = new List<string>();
    FieldList.addAll(FieldSet);
    FieldList.sort();
    Component.Apex.PageBlockSection pbs = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSection(columns = 2);

    for (string fieldName : FieldList)
    {
        Component.Apex.PageBlockSectionItem pbsi = new Component.Apex.PageBlockSectionItem();
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult field = (FieldMap.get(fieldName)).getDescribe();

        if (field.isUpdateable() && field.IsAccessible())
        {
            Schema.DisplayType dt = field.getType();
            Component.Apex.OutputLabel lblText = new Component.Apex.OutputLabel(escape = false);
            lblText.value = field.getLabel();
            pbsi.childComponents.add(lblText);

            Component.Apex.SelectList selList = new Component.Apex.SelectList(id = field.getName(), multiselect = false, size = 1, style = 'width:200px;');

            if (dt == Schema.DisplayType.Integer || dt == Schema.DisplayType.Double || dt == Schema.DisplayType.Currency || dt == Schema.DisplayType.Percent)
            {
                AddSelectOption(selList, 'Keep highest value');
                AddSelectOption(selList, 'Keep lowest value');
                AddSelectOption(selList, 'Keep master value');
                pbsi.childComponents.add(selList);
                pbs.childComponents.add(pbsi);
            }
        }
    }

    return pbs;
}

private void AddSelectOption(Component.Apex.SelectList selList, string option)
{
     Component.Apex.SelectOption selOption = new Component.Apex.SelectOption();
     selOption.itemLabel = option;
     selOption.itemValue = option;
     selList.childComponents.add(selOption);
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

just bind the value attribute of the dynamically created select list to a string property using expression syntax like:

```
String selectedValue {get; set;}
...
setList.expressions.value = '{!selectedValue}';
```

the property should then store the selected value just as it would in a static declarative definition of the select list.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however when dynamically creating the selectlists, I do not know how many fields will be in the object and therefore cannot create correct number of variables to hold the values of each. I was wondering if there was a way to directly reference the value on the page or something???

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use dynamic visualforce binding. I.E.

```
map<String,String> FieldToString {get; set;}
...
selList.expressions.value = '{!FieldToString[\'' + fieldname + '\']}';
```

However, I have never used dynamic visualforce bindings within dynamic visualforce so caveat emptor.